# How to add a base class to a vector of derived classes

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have a `std::vector` that holds shared pointers to a derived class `cDerivedClass`, I also have shared pointers for the base class too. So something like this:

```
typedef SHARED_PTR<cBaseClass> cBaseClassPtr;

typedef SHARED_PTR<cDerivedClass> cDerivedClassPtr;

std::vector<cDerivedClassPtr> vDerivedPtrList;
```

Now if I want to have a `CDerivedClass::AddComponent(cBaseClassPtr inpBaseClass)` method that takes an argument of type cBaseClassPtr and adds it to the vector (vDerivedPtrList) of derived classes, how would I go about doing this?

I know dynamic_cast won't work since base-to-derived conversions are not allowed with dynamic casts unless the base class is polymorphic. I've tried static casting the cBaseClassPtr to a cDerivedClassPtr, but I'm thrown an error.

```
void cDerivedClass::AddComponent(cBaseClassPtr inpBaseClass)
{
    MY_ASSERT(inpBaseClass, "Component cannot be NULL");

    cDerivedClassPtr pDerviedPtrToAdd = static_cast<cDerivedClassPtr>(inpBaseClass);

    this->mvComponentList.push_back(pDerviedPtrToAdd);
}
```

Edit: To be exact this is the error I'm getting:

```
No matching conversion of static_cast from 'cBaseClassPtr' (aka 'shared_ptr<cBaseClassPtr>') to 'cDerivedClassPtr' (aka 'shared_ptr<cDerivedClassPtr>');
```

I'm using boost's implementation of smart pointers[`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)

Comment: Why would you want to do that. Casting from base to derived class  is a no no...  Unless you know that base is the derived,  but that could point to a bad design.

Comment: Personally, I see a design flaw here.

Answer (score 0):

If your `CDerivedClass::AddComponent` function can only really deal with `cDerivedClassPtr`s, then adjust its signature accordingly :

```
CDerivedClass::AddComponent(cDerivedClassPtr inpDerivedClass)
```

If it should be able to deal with `cBaseClassPtr`, then adjust the definition of `vDerivedPtrList` to hold `cBaseClassPtr`s :

```
std::vector<cBaseClassPtr> vBasePtrList;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know exactly what you are trying to do here, and what smart-pointer implementation you are using.

Why is your base class not polymorphic? If it were you could use some kind of double-dispatch to get it to add itself to an appropriate collection.

If there is a different vector for each derivation, then each derived class would know which one it is supposed to add itself to.

You will need your base class to derive from enable_shared_From_this so it can shared-pointer itself if it is already currently shared_ptred (which presumably it is): although that will shared_ptr itself into the base type you can then create another shared_ptr based on the life of the first and put that in the collection.

(That is assuming you are using boost and I think std has the same interface)